# mapping jj to escape in macvim works but not in terminal vim

Tags: macos, vim, terminal, macvim, iterm2

In my vimrc I have:

```
inoremap jj <ESC>
```

Using the latest macvim I can hit jj and i'll jump from insert to command mode, but using the same vimrc with just regular vim in iterm2 it just inserts two 'j's...

Is there a setting for vim or iterm that I need to set to make it work?

I am currently using Yosemite but the problem existed in Maverics as well.
Also the key mapping doesnt work in osx's Terminal.app either.

More research seems to show that vim isnt recognizing the double press of any key for me. even if i do:

```
inoremap jj :hello
```

I still dont see it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer!
A while back I added a small bit into my vimrc to remove the insert leave delay:

```
if ! has('gui_running')
  set ttimeoutlen=10
  augroup FastEscape
    autocmd!
    au InsertEnter * set timeoutlen=0
    au InsertLeave * set timeoutlen=1000
  augroup END
endif
```

I removed this and now jj works!

Answer (score 0):

I found something at [github](https://github.com/christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator/issues/33) talking about an iTerm issue in Yosemite. Here is the issue described through [Homebrew's issues](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/29843).

Are you using Yosemite? Does the key bindings work correctly in Terminal? According to this issue it seems to be something with iTerm in Yosemite.

Comment: Sorry I didnt specify! I am currently using yosemite BUT the problem existed in maverics as well, also the problem exists in osx's terminal as well

Answer (score 0):

From the terminal vim try running `:imap`.  This should list all of the insert mode mappings.  Does the `jj` mapping show up?  If not, try defining the mapping manually from that vim and see if it works.

My guess would be that your terminal is running a different version of vim that is reading a vimrc from a different location.  Try `:echo $MYVIMRC` from both the terminal vim and macvim to see if they refer to the same file.  If they are different you could just add the mapping to the vimrc that the terminal vim is using.  It would be better, though, to reconcile the differences in the vim versions so you don't have to maintain two configuration files.

Comment: If I run imap it shows the keymapping, I have confirmed that macvim is using the same vimrc as terminal vim